# Why SQL Server columns are always lower case?

Tags: sql-server, performance, lowercase

I have been working for a while with SQL Server and I noticed that Microsoft always uses lower cases for all the standard columns (i.g. in the master db). Is there a good reason for following this in my own models? Maybe a performance reason?

[image]

Comment: Most likely because it's slower (to type) column names that have mixed case especially when they already have underscores. Why not all caps then? It's also quicker to read all lower case (less of a need to re-size columns and side-scroll).

Comment: Keeping your naming convension to a standard across your DB would be the good reason. Personally, I prefer Camel Casing when it comes to naming fields in SQL. e.g. LastModified, VersionNumber, LastRunDate etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helps when the server is configured with case sensitive collation. If that were the case, then having mixed case names will sure cause a lot of headaches.

How do I know? I was stuck with sp_MSforeachdb in a multiple server scenario and one server had a case sensitive collation. Took me a lot longer than it would have otherwise, to figure out the MS is caps, even with an underscore.

Raj

Comment: Very interesting problem there. Must have driven you mad

Answer (score 2):

Reasons are convention and consistency. There is no performance benefit here. They decided this is our coding convention and stuck with it.

Comment: +1. This is the funny part here - one can argue about the spelling per se, but the question makes it sound like the poster never used a coding standard. It is CONSISTENT, which is good.